# Probability that two points (any where on the curve) are a set number of standard deviations apart on a normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

So, here is the question:

*You buy two pieces of pipe from supplier A, and the inner diameter has a normal distribution of N(muA, sigmaA^2) = N(8.02, 0.1^2). You want these two pipes to butt together nicely and not to make ugly turbulent flow.*

*What is the probability of the diameters of two randomly picked pipes differing by more than 0.3mm?*

The crux is that these two points can occur anywhere on the normal distribution, although some places will be more likely, so the area between them will not be fixed. I think it might be something to do with mean values, but I'm absolutely stumped so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bonus round:

*You randomly pick one pipe from the first supplier A, and randomly pick another from a second supplier B, supplier B's inner pipe diameters are described by another normal distribution N(muA, sigmaA^2) = N(7.95, 0.08^2).*

*What is the probability that the diameter of the two pipes differ by more than 0.3mm?*

The answers are apparently 0.03 and 0.04

I'm an engineer-to-be so please be gentle if hardcore maths notation is needed

Good luck and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is the following:

Assume you have two independent random variables $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$, then for their difference the following holds:

$$ X_1 - X_2 \sim N(\mu_1 - \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 )$$

For a proof, see for example the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

Now, for your case, notice that you are looking for the probability $\Pr(|X_1 - X_2| > 0.03)$.

This can be calculated with the corresponding distribution function $F_Z$ as follows (where $Z:= X_1 - X_2$ for ease of notation).

$$\Pr(|Z| > 0.03) = \Pr(Z < -0.03) + \Pr(Z>0.03) = F_Z(-0.03) + 1 - F_Z(0.03)$$

In the first case $Z \sim N(0, 0.02)$, so that the probability is approximately 0.034 and in the second case $Z \sim N(0.07, 0.0164)$ and $\Pr(|Z| > 0.03) \approx 0.038$.